# iPhone -Pthread condition signal not unblocking the waiting thread

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two threads running as following. The code works perfectly on iPhone simulator but not on the device. On iPhone ( have ios 5.1 running) thread A signals on the condition but thread B is waiting on the condition indefinitely.

In thread A when data is ready to be processed:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
outstandingSig++;
pthread_cond_signal(&condVar);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

In thread B:

```
 while(1) 
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while(outstandingSig == 0)
   {
    pthread_cond_wait(&condVar, &mutex);
   }

  outstandingSig = 0;  //Reset outstanding signals
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

 // process data
}
```

Any suggestions why it's behaving differently on the device? What could be causing thread B not to consume the signal? And why different behavior on the simulator and the device?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get to the bottom of this or find a work-around? I think I am having a similar problem with hanging on a pthread_cond_wait on the iPhone device.

The condition is signalled correctly on the iOS Simulator but it hangs when running on the iPhone. If I pause execution and then resume, the condition is satisfied and execution continues.

I did notice however, that the implementation of pthread_cond_wait is different on different platforms.

iPhone:

> libsystem_c.dylib'pthread_cond_wait

iOS Simulator:

> libsystem_c.dylib'pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003

Comment: Changing the debugger to GDB helped. Hope it works for you. If you do come across another solution, do post